# can i use multiple VMs with single boot disk for autoscaling in google cloud

Tags: load-balancing, lamp, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autoscaling

My Average CPU loading about 40-50%, but in peak time  (generally 4 hours)server response time is too late.

How to overcome this issue?

Is there any other way to add additional CPU power in prescribed time.

in autoscaling every VM creating bootdisk from image snapshot.

for this i have to automate snapshots. but every VM also have different IP.

where to point the domain DNS.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case managed instance group with [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/) and [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/) would be a good solution. When you receive more traffic autoscaler will add more instances and when the traffic goes down instances will be delete from the instance group. The load balancer will take care of distributing traffic among instances. It also has static IP which you can used to map your domain.

Only the non-root/non-boot GCE disks can be attached to [multiple instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#use_multi_instances) in **read only mode**, which I think is not what you need.

Comment: the problem is different ips for different instances and the different boot disks not from the root disk only from snapshot and it will lost after the load balance. i really not understand this case. what if i updated website and instance and disk will be deleted. then where is my updated data during peak.

Comment: You can take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfbEwfYjKl4) which explains how autoscaling works on GCE.